# BigQuery return all datasets without pageToken?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way using bigquery API to return all datasets without having to deal with the pagination system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now  - there is a hard limit of 1000 datasets per request. You can change it to lower, but not to higher!
If you have more than 1K datasets in your project  - there is no way to avoid use of page token!

Comment: Interesting. I'm getting the page token but do not have more that 1000 datasets, I don't even think I have more than 100. Is there another Parma I should pass with my request?

Comment: try to set `maxResults` to 1000, (the default is most likely 10 - not sure of exact default number - but close to it) :o)